# Open Container App from Share Extenion

Tags: ios, deep-linking, openurl, ios8-share-extension

So I've found that the you cannot open URLs (and therefore deeplinks) from Share Extensions in iOS. But I'm wondering if there is any way to open the container app of the extension.

For instance, in my app the share extension will only work if you are logged in, so if you tap the extension it will present an alert view telling you so. But I want a button on that alert view to bring you into the container app to make it easier to log in.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: The Today extension is the only one allowed to open the containing app. For the rest of app extensions, it is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple does not permit this. It's not an accident that you can't open URLs from share extensions. There have been workarounds in some versions of iOS, but Apple has closed them, because they apparently considered them to be bugs. The intended behavior is apparently that a share extension must be able to do whatever it needs to have done without relying on the containing app.

Comment: That makes sense. I can see why apple would restrict the ability to open URLs and other apps, but it seems a bit odd to not have the ability to open the app that the extension belongs to. Anyway, thanks for the help!